# Grafana: how to get data about internal topics of kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana

I want to get the message in rate of the __consumer_offsets topic.
But if I put this query in grafana:

> rate(kafka_server_brokertopicmetrics_messagesin_total{topic="__consumer_offsets"}[1m])

it shows me NO DATA.

It does work with other topics. But with the __consumer_offsets topic, no.

Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have group consumers?

Comment: @nipuna no. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka `__consumer_offsets` topic getting messages only you have group consumers from that cluster.

When you start a group consumer for topic, for each partition, consumed last offset saved in `__consumer_offsets` topic for that group consumer.

So if you haven't any group consumer in your cluster, it is obvious that your `__consumer_offsets` has no any messages. Then There is no data to show in your `grafana dashboard` for metrics `message in rate` of the `__consumer_offsets` topic.